# How to block non-free with apt preferences?

Tags: debian, apt

I want to block all packages from `non-free`, except for those that I 
name explicitly. Currently, I have:

`/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

`/etc/apt/preferences.d/non-free_policy` :

```
Explanation: Disable packages from `non-free` tree by default
Package: *
Pin: release c=non-free
Pin-Priority: -1
```

(The idea is, that I add an explicit stanza for every package I want from non-free.)

But it doesn't work:

```
root@silber:/etc/apt/preferences.d# apt-get -s install firmware-linux-nonfree
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
  firmware-linux-nonfree
0 aktualisiert, 1 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Inst firmware-linux-nonfree (0.43 Debian:8.4/stable [all])
Conf firmware-linux-nonfree (0.43 Debian:8.4/stable [all])
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You explicitly told `apt-get` to install `firmware-linux-nonfree`.  IIRC, the only effect pinning can have in that situation is to select which debian release (e.g. 'stable' or 'sid') or third party repo (e.g. 'deb-multimedia.org') to install from, and/or which version to install.   Your pin rule **WILL** block non-free packages, except those that you explicitly install on an `apt-get install` command line....you don't need an exception rule for each package.

Comment: @cas: Another example `apt-get -s install raccoon` tells me, that it would install `autodocktools`  from non-free, which I didn't call explicitely. Is this still what you woud expect? Can I somehow prevent this?

Comment: `raccoon` depends on `autodocktools`.  If you tell `apt-get`  to install `racooon`, what do you expect will happen?  `apt-get` will do what it needs to in order to complete your instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure you don't have another, more general pin priority which takes priority over your `non-free`-excluding rule. (This includes the `APT::Default-Release` configuration setting which assigns a high priority to the given release.)

For example, if your `/etc/apt/preferences` file (or another file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`) contains something like the following:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 200
```

then `unstable` packages will have pin priority 200, regardless of the component. To make this work with your additional file, you should change this to

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable, c=main
Pin-Priority: 200
```

(and add an additional stanza for `contrib` if you care about that). (In your case you would have `stable` of course.)

You can check the effect of your pin priorities by running

```
apt-cache policy
```

If your `non-free`-excluding configuration is working correctly, you should see entries for all the suites you're tracking, on `non-free`, with a pin-priority of -1. Once that's working, you'll find that you can no longer install `raccoon`, or in fact any `non-free` package (even if mentioned explicitly) — you'll need to add the `non-free` packages you want to your configuration file, with an appropriate pin priority.

As an example, here’s the setup I use: I have a file named `/etc/apt/preferences.d/non-free` containing

```
Package: intel-microcode
Pin: release n=buster, c=non-free
Pin-Priority: 100

Explanation: Disable packages from non-free tree by default
Package: *
Pin: release c=non-free
Pin-Priority: -1
```

Non-free packages still appear in searches, but I can’t install them:

```
$ sudo apt install lmbench
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package lmbench is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'lmbench' has no installation candidate
```

and `apt policy` agrees:

```
$ apt policy lmbench
lmbench:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     3.0-a9+debian.1-2 -1
         -1 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 Packages
         -1 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian testing/non-free amd64 Packages
         -1 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian unstable/non-free amd64 Packages
```

But `intel-microcode` is installable and upgradable. Thus after a forced downgrade to the oldstable version, I get

```
$ apt policy intel-microcode
intel-microcode:
  Installed: 3.20190618.1~deb9u1
  Candidate: 3.20190618.1
  Version table:
     3.20190618.1 100
         -1 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 Packages
         -1 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian testing/non-free amd64 Packages
         -1 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian unstable/non-free amd64 Packages
 *** 3.20190618.1~deb9u1 100
        100 /usr/var/lib/dpkg/status

$ apt list --upgradable
intel-microcode/stable,testing,unstable 3.20190618.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.20190618.1~deb9u1]
```

The `apt policy` output ends up somewhat confusing — refer to the “Candidate” line to see what’s really going to happen.

Comment: My problem was, that I had the line `APT::Default-Release "jessie";` in a file in `/etc/apt.conf.d`, which assinged a high priority to all packages from jessie. `apt-cache policy` helped to detect that. Thank you.

Comment: @MaxKubierschky thanks, I've (belatedly) updated my answer to include that.

Comment: I have been trying to do this. I got error `Invalid record in the preferences file /etc/apt/preferences.d/apt-preferences-non-free-policy, no Package header` because of `Explanation:` I added a `#` in front of this line to fix it. It no longer errors, but I see no additional output from `apt-cache policy`

Comment: I then added non-free to sources, to see if that would fix it. It did.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I’ve added details of my setup.

Comment: I think the only differences are an unimportant n=buster, in yours (Mine is at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/534340/4778 ); I also chose different priorities (does it matter), and I had to add `iucode-tool` to get `intel-microcode` to work, because of dependencies.

Comment: Right, because you’re blocking contrib, which I’m not. Priorities don’t matter. I specify `n=buster` to ensure that I only get Buster upgrades.

Comment: Is the buster (at least normally) dealt with by the source list? It would be nice if there was a rule to make dependencies have a different (positive) priority). I will read manual again.

Comment: Yes, most users should only have Buster in their repositories. I have multiple suites so I prefer to be specific ;-).

Comment: Regarding your second point about dependencies, I rather like the fact that you need to specify dependencies’ priorities too (that way the pin priorities give an exhaustive list of all non-free packages which are allowed to be installed); but again my use-case is slightly different from your since I don’t block contrib.