# Debian: limit non-free to just a few firmware packages

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, repository, firmware

I am running Debian 10 (Buster). I would like to run a 100% free system. However, I need a few non-free firmware packages, because my hardware is not free.

Therefore, I would like to install the non-free firmware packages that my hardware needs, but no more. This may mean I will have non-free hardware and firmware, but everything above this will be free.

**How do I enable non-free for these packages, but not have the package manager tell me about, or install other non-free packages?**

---

I have also been using `equivs-control` to create `deb`s. Therefore, my preferred answer will be how to create a non-free deb that depends on the desired firmware. I can then install that package and it will pull in the firmware packages. However, other solutions will also be accepted.

Comment: I use [this approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284582/86440), I could expand on that if you’re interested.

Comment: @StephenKitt it looks like the right thing, but a lot of the answer I need seem to be in the question. I you but it all in one place, then I will issue a bounty in a day or two (when it is allowed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @StephenKitt, question/answer [How to block non-free with apt preferences?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284582/86440) and the manual, I discovered how to block installation of the non-free, except the specified ones. **However they are still listed in search and in `apper`.**

Create a file `apt-preferences-non-free-policy` (**note it contains the packages that I want/need**), with content

```
#Explanation: don't install non-free, except some firmware

Package: *
Pin: release c=non-free
Pin-Priority: -10

Package: *
Pin: release c=contrib
Pin-Priority: -10

#################################################
#Specify individual packages

Package: intel-microcode
Pin: release c=non-free
Pin-Priority: 101

Package: firmware-iwlwifi
Pin: release c=non-free
Pin-Priority: 101

#This is a dependency of intel-microcode
Package: iucode-tool
Pin: release c=contrib
Pin-Priority: 101
```

Create file `apt-source-list-non-free.list` (**change for your distro/release**), containing

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster non-free contrib
```

Copy into place

```
sudo cp -t /etc/apt/preferences.d/ apt-preferences-non-free-policy
sudo cp -t /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ apt-source-list-non-free.list
```

check

```
apt-cache policy
```

Then install

```
sudo apt install intel-microcode firmware-iwlwifi
```